Proper usage of the 'Mindstorms' tag
The two tags rcx and nxt which both represent the two flagship Mindstorms products have all been tagged with the mindstorms tag. Perhaps we should use the Mindstorms tag to refer to general Mindstorms questions instead?
We had a similar issue on Bicycles.SE (albeit the regional tag was a meta tag). 
I think it's important we establish this tags usage at an early stage.

If the question is specific to nxt only, tag it nxt.  If it's more general, but your use-case is the NXT, then tag it with both.  It's more general, tag it with mindstorms only.
For example, my question from yesterday, How much depth does the NXT battery pack add? I tagged nxt, but NOT mindstorms.  The mindstorms was added by someone else, and I would argue isn't needed for that question, as it is very specifically about the NXT and not applicable to any other mindstorms series.
Then How to get started with Mindstorms? is mindstorms and not nxt, which, due it its more general nature seems right to me.
With Can I use RCX sensors and motors with the NXT brick?, I think it make sense to have mindstorms+nxt+rcx as you're crossing mindstorms lines and beginning to get a broader scope.

To add further weight: since this was discussed, the SE engine now pre-pends the most popular tag to the question's title <meta> tag all these posts will appear as "mindstorms - ..." in tabs and some searches, instead of the more relevant "nxt" or "ev3".

I'm not sure about this, one one hand I would tend to think nxt and rcx questions are clearly about Mindstorms and as such don't require an additional tag, as you suggest.
Apparently, we discussed some of this before (well, it was more about merging tags, but it's the same tags we talked about) and from there we recommended to use either nxt or rcx in the wiki description of mindstorms - although we didn't say to use it instead.

I don't think they're quite the same questions. I would strongly disagree merging the two tags, as you rightly said they are very different.

I look at it in a similar way to SO's having a .NET tag as well as C# and VB - indeed looking at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net you see questions tagged .NET and C# even though .NET is pretty much implied by the C# tag.

I admit that my argument doesn't make it right.

Right maybe not, but it's interesting anyway, I was wondering if SO had such examples but wasn't sure what to too for - I know there are so many variants of [tag:excel] for example but you example is more similar to ours

On SO we have .net and c# tags, and most of the questions are tagged by both, because at least C#-questions are the subset of .NET-questions.
So I would expect all the nxt questions to be tagged with mindstorms, but not vice versa.

But not all c# questions are tagged with .Net.

@Zhaph: ~85% from my pov

Hmm, a quick look at the tag pages shows me: Questions tagged "C#": ~245,761; Questions tagged ".NET": ~100,484; Questions tagged both "C#" and ".NET": ~50,979 (and only 4,772 tagged "VB.NET" and ".NET"). So it's closer to 50% of .NET questions are tagged with C#, and less than a quarter of the C# questions are tagged .NET.

@Zhaph: Statistics beat me :) But actually I think that in previous years it was not in common use to tag by both as it is now day. For example, I have 1k in [tag:c#] and 850 in [tag:.net].
